# How to speed up loading table rows when using datatable in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatable

Im using datatable and I am facing a very strange situation. The data needs a long time to appear, especially if the records are very large.
I'm not using Yajra and not looking for using it in laravel, with datatable all are fine but this is the isuue I face now, is there any solution to make data fast? I know may I have to use pagination but pagination without ajax is a big problem specially the search in datatable
Hope you have solution for this issue

**Controller:**

```
  public function index()
   {
    $data = User::all();

   return view('managedashboard.ownerdashboard.allcustomers.archive', compact('data'));
     }
```

**Datatable:**

```
        TableDatatablesEditable = function() {
            var e = function() {
                var e = $("#sample_1"),
                    t = e.dataTable({
                        dom: "Bfrtip",
                        buttons: [{
                            extend: "print",
                       exportOptions: {
                             columns: ['.export'],
                                      },
                            className: "btn dark btn-outline"
                        }, {
                            extend: "pdf",
                        exportOptions: {
                             columns: ['.export'],
                                      },                       
                            className: "btn green btn-outline"
                        }, {
                            extend: 'csvHtml5',
                       exportOptions: {
                             columns: ['.export'],
                                      },


                       className: "btn-outline"
                        }],
                        language: {
                            lengthMenu: " _MENU_ records"
                        },
                        columnDefs: [{
                            orderable: !0,
                            targets: [0]
                        }, {
                            searchable: !0,
                            targets: [0]
                        }],
                        order: [
                            [2, "desc"]
                        ],
                        lengthMenu: [
                            [5, 10, 15, 20, -1],
                            [5, 10, 15, 20, "All"]
                        ],
                        pageLength: 20,
                        dom: "<'row' <'col-md-12'B>><'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r><'table-scrollable't><'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>"
                    });
                $("#sample_editable_1_wrapper");
                e.on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var a = $(this).parents("tr")[0],
                        l = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id"),
                        n = {
                            _token: $("input[name='_token']").val()
                        };
                    n = jQuery.param(n), BootstrapDialog.confirm("Are you sure?", function(e) {
                        if (e) {
                            var o = n,
                                r = "/" + locationUrl[3]+"/"+locationUrl[4] + "/" + l;
                            ajaxCall("DELETE", r, o, "result", "", !1, "delete"), t.fnDeleteRow(a)
                        }
                    })
                })
            };
            return {
                init: function() {
                    e()
                }
            }
        }();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        TableDatatablesEditable.init()
    });
```

php jquery ajax datata

Comment: Why don't you paging instead of load all ?

Comment: Try server side data table this will gives all features of data table.Or try adding pagination as @phong already comment there

Comment: @GorkhaliKhadka can you tell me how to do this please?

Comment: @Phong because I want to be in the same page when using serach ajax in datatable for all records

Comment: May this can help you https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/1872#issuecomment-432436805

Comment: It seems to me that getting all records at the same time is not a good idea. If a user wants to search, why don't you give them the filter criteria?

Comment: @Phong you know in datatable there is input field for searching in the whole table records for any text in the columns

Comment: so do filter in backend...

Answer (score 3):

Try this example. This is only example.

Change as per your requirement.
Include in header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.12/datatables.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.12/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

Your table looks like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
               <table class="table table-bordered" id="posts">
                    <thead>
                           <th>Id</th>
                           <th>Title</th>
                           <th>Body</th>
                           <th>Created At</th>
                           <th>Options</th>
                    </thead>                
               </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

Your javascript code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#posts').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax":{
                     "url": "{{ url('allposts') }}",
                     "dataType": "json",
                     "type": "POST",
                     "data":{ _token: "{{csrf_token()}}"}
                   },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "title" },
                { "data": "body" },
                { "data": "created_at" },
                { "data": "options" }
            ]    

        });
    });
</script>
```

And finally Your controller should be.

```
public function allPosts(Request $request)
    {

        $columns = array( 
                            0 =>'id', 
                            1 =>'title',
                            2=> 'body',
                            3=> 'created_at',
                            4=> 'id',
                        );

        $totalData = Post::count();

        $totalFiltered = $totalData; 

        $limit = $request->input('length');
        $start = $request->input('start');
        $order = $columns[$request->input('order.0.column')];
        $dir = $request->input('order.0.dir');

        if(empty($request->input('search.value')))
        {            
            $posts = Post::offset($start)
                         ->limit($limit)
                         ->orderBy($order,$dir)
                         ->get();
        }
        else {
            $search = $request->input('search.value'); 

            $posts =  Post::where('id','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
                            ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE',"%{$search}%")
                            ->offset($start)
                            ->limit($limit)
                            ->orderBy($order,$dir)
                            ->get();

            $totalFiltered = Post::where('id','LIKE',"%{$search}%")
                             ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE',"%{$search}%")
                             ->count();
        }

        $data = array();
        if(!empty($posts))
        {
            foreach ($posts as $post)
            {
                $show =  route('posts.show',$post->id);
                $edit =  route('posts.edit',$post->id);

                $nestedData['id'] = $post->id;
                $nestedData['title'] = $post->title;
                $nestedData['body'] = substr(strip_tags($post->body),0,50)."...";
                $nestedData['created_at'] = date('j M Y h:i a',strtotime($post->created_at));
                $nestedData['options'] = "&emsp;<a href='{$show}' title='SHOW' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list'></span></a>
                                          &emsp;<a href='{$edit}' title='EDIT' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></a>";
                $data[] = $nestedData;

            }
        }

        $json_data = array(
                    "draw"            => intval($request->input('draw')),  
                    "recordsTotal"    => intval($totalData),  
                    "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered), 
                    "data"            => $data   
                    );

        echo json_encode($json_data); 

    }
```